# h:panelgroup seems to inherit the `dir` tag but doesn't support it. How Do I define `dir` per panelGroup?

Tags: html, jsf

I have a page that's direction oriented and so I usually define the `dir` tag for an entire form.

I have a few `h:panelgroup` objects who are supposed to group some components in a row in a table.

Problem is, some of these `h:panelGroup` components are supposed to remain in ltr direction no matter what they inherit but the `h:panelGroup` component doesn't support the `dir` tag.

I can use a `h:panelGrid` with more columns than components to resolve this, but it seems odd that there is no cleaner solution...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add styleClass attribute, and use the [css direction property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_text_direction.asp).

```
.ltr {
    direction: ltr;
}
.rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

So you can use `styleClass="rtl"`, and  `styleClass="ltr"`.